# How to exclude characters in beginning and end

Tags: python

How do I create a pattern that does not start or end with a ',' but can have one in between. The whole pattern should also not include any characters other that alphanumeric (',' being the exception)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please also add a short code snippet that helps users to understand your question further.

Comment: `",,,hello, world,,,".strip(",")`

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing [more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I suggest reading [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to ***create a pattern***, so I'm assuming you mean that you want to generate a string. You're going to need to define some constraints such as the character-set (which you already have) the length of the string you want to generate, and the method which we use to pick characters. If there are additional constraints like grammar rules, you'd need to add those in, too, but I'll just stick with what you originally asked.

`import random` / `random.choice` seems like a good method for picking characters because it's easy to use and understand. You might have a function that looks like this --

```py
def create(length):
    string = ""
    for x in range(0, length):
        if x != 0 != length: # If we aren't at the beginning or end
          # A-Z, 0-9, and comma allowed in middle
          string = string + random.choice('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789,')
        else:
          # A-Z, 0-9, no comma or space allowed
          string = string + random.choice('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789')
    return(string)
```

We can specify how long we want the pattern to be, and when we're at the beginning or end of the string, it'll only pick a random alphanumeric character to add to the string.

And if you `print(create(10))`, you're get return values that look like this -- `LL4VWCICC7`, `R03MKE17JE`, `HXTKB,3FWV` -- commas allowed, but never at the beginning or end.